# Calling methods in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I have this method:

```
checkFancyBox=function(){
  ldValue=LD(user,'admin')+LD(pass,'admin');
  if(ldValue<2){
    myHashMap[pass.concat(user)]=ldValue;
    $.fancybox({
      content: "<span style='color:black'>Wrong username or password. </span>", 
      showCloseButton: true,
      transitionIn: "elastic"
    });
    $('#funny').show("");
    return false;  
  }
};
```

when it is placed within the :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  //... 
  checkFancyBox(); 
  //...
  checkFancyBox=function(){ /*...*/ };
};
```

it crashes and instantly refreshed,

and when when it is placed outside the $(document).ready.... it is working,

but for some reason it does not displays the content of the fancybox,

and again, instantly refreshes.

where should i place it and how to make it show the content and continue only if the

'close' button on fancybox is pressed?

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hoisting issue.

```
checkFancyBox=function(){...};
};
```

Hoists the **declaration** to the top of the function, but not the **initialization**.  So when you have

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... 
     //checkFancyBox declaration is hoisted to here, and is undefined
     checkFancyBox(); //calling an undefined variable is an error

     checkFancyBox = function(){...}; //now checkFancyBox is initialized, but too late to prevent the error
     };
```

Placing this declaration **outside** of the `document.ready` handler causes this declaration and initialization to happen before the handler is run, so `checkFancyBox` has a value, and can be called.  If you choose to stick with your original way of declaring the function, make sure you put a `var` in front of it.

```
var checkFancyBox = function(){...};
```

But note that the function can simply be declared like this

```
function checkFancyBox(){
  //...
}
```

If on the other hand you want the function to be local to your document.ready handler, then simply move the declaration to the top of that handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... 
    var checkFancyBox = function(){...};
    //checkFancyBox declaration and initialization are both accomplished, 
    //and the function is safe to call

    checkFancyBox();
};
```

Comment: @Itzik984 - placing the function outside of your document.ready handler is definitely the right way to declare the function, as you saw by the fact that no error occurred.  I'm afraid there's not enough code above to figure out why it's not working.  I would just declare the function correctly, gather all the related code, and post a new question.  I'm sure there are some fancybox experts around who can help you.

Comment: i placed it outside the doc.ready and it works, but instantly refreshes, and does not show the message needed. am i doing something wrong with the fancybox? how to stop it from refreshing?

Comment: @Itzik984 - I'm afraid I'm not a fancybox expert.  As I said, gather up *all* the related code to the checkFancyBox function, and post a new question.